# Wampache Error number: 10061 - Error string: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: wampserver

Using a fresh install of wampserver 3.2.6 on windows server 2019 I get error 10061, I have port forwarded on my router and opened the port on the firewall, but have not been able to get it to function. Ive looked using netstat but no programs are using this port.

error from checking wampache

> ***** Test which uses port 8081 *****
>
> ===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 8081 =====
>
> Port 8081 is not found associated with TCP protocol Port 8081 is not
> found associated with TCP protocol
>
> ===== Tested by attempting to open a socket on port 8081 =====
>
> Your port 8081 seems not actually used. Unable to initiate a socket
> connection Error number: 10061 - Error string: No connection could be
> made because the target machine actively refused it.
>
> --- Do you want to copy the results into Clipboard?
> --- Press the Y key to confirm - Press ENTER to continue...

result of checking state of services

> State of services:
>
> The service 'wampapache64' is NOT started  EXIT error code:1066  Help
> message for error code 1066 is:The service has returned a
> service-specific error code.
>
> > > > AH00015: Unable to open logs     .
> > > > AH00451: no listening sockets available, shutting down     .
>
> The service 'wampmysqld64' is started  Service Session : LocalSystem
>
> The service 'wampmariadb64' is started  Service Session : LocalSystem
>
> WampServer (Apache, PHP and MySQL) will not function properly if any
> service 'wampapache64' 'wampmysqld64' 'wampmariadb64'  is not started.
>
> all services BINARY_PATH_NAME are OK
>
> --- Do you want to copy the results into Clipboard?
> --- Press the Y key to confirm - Press ENTER to continue...

Comment: Look at the Event Viewer, something is stopping Apache starting, but it will still have written to the event log

Comment: alright i looked into that and it appears the PHP version i was using was causing the error. I changed the version wampserver was using and it works. thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there a way to mark this as solved?

Comment: Yes write your own answer.

Comment: Looks like you had something else, probably IIS and maybe other things as well using port 80